# why do we need body parser in an express application?

Tags: node.js, json, express

I don't understand why we need body-parser in an Express application, as we can get data without using body-parser. And what does it do actually and how?

Comment: It's only about the fact that you write a single line and you get parsed json or a single line to get object from url-encoded form. Write the parser yourself and you end up with tens or maybe hundreds of lines of code. Just reading the body is a few tens of lines of code, you don't get the body automaticaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally we use `body parser` to handle incoming request bodies. request like JSON, urlencoded etc but now team behind `express` has added it as a global core module, so you dont need to install/import `body parser` again

instead of doing

```
import bodyparser = require("body-parser")
import express = require("express")

const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

You Can now do

```
import express = require("express")

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of express doesn't require setting up `body-parser` as it is inbuilt in to express.

see this [PR](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2211) for more details